# Neo4j doesn't autostart after deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, jruby, neo4j

I'm trying to deploy a jruby rails app using the neo4j gem to Heroku.  Running locally works fine but when I hit #new (//new) at Heroku's end, I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `reference_node' for nil:NilClass):
```

After [some research][1], it seemed like my Neo4j server wasn't even running.

So I had to do

```
heroku run rails console
```

then

```
Neo4j.start
```

..in order to get my app working.  But why doesn't Neo4j know to just wake up and start?

This is my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      mail (~> 2.5.3)
    actionpack (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.13)
      activemodel (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
    activesupport (3.2.13)
      i18n (= 0.6.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
    diff-lcs (1.2.4)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (1.4.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    hike (1.2.2)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (2.2.1)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.7.7-java)
    mail (2.5.3)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.23)
    multi_json (1.7.2)
    neo4j (2.2.3-java)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0, < 3.3)
      neo4j-wrapper (= 2.2.3)
      orm_adapter (>= 0.0.3)
      railties (>= 3.0.0, < 3.3)
    neo4j-community (1.8.1-java)
    neo4j-core (2.2.3-java)
      neo4j-community (>= 1.8.1, < 1.9)
      neo4j-cypher (~> 1.0.0)
    neo4j-cypher (1.0.0)
    neo4j-wrapper (2.2.3-java)
      neo4j-core (= 2.2.3)
    orm_adapter (0.4.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    puma (1.6.3-java)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    rack (1.4.5)
    rack-cache (1.2)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.13)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activerecord (= 3.2.13)
      activeresource (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.13)
    railties (3.2.13)
      actionpack (= 3.2.13)
      activesupport (= 3.2.13)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (10.0.4)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rspec-core (2.13.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
    rspec-rails (2.13.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.13.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.13.0)
    sass (3.2.8)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.2)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    therubyrhino (2.0.2)
      therubyrhino_jar (>= 1.7.3)
    therubyrhino_jar (1.7.4)
    thor (0.18.1)
    tilt (1.3.7)
    treetop (1.4.12)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.37)
    uglifier (2.0.1)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  java

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  neo4j (>= 2.2.3)
  puma
  rails (= 3.2.13)
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  therubyrhino
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely because Neo4j start-up is not (yet) thread-safe. Neo4j will actually start up the first time you hit your app. However, depending on the type of request(s), you could encounter the error described above from that point forward. Specifically, multiple requests to the app while Neo4j is starting up will result in errors until the app is restarted.

I submitted a fix for this (see [here](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-core/pull/23), [here](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/issues/237), and [here](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j/pull/238)) and it has been merged. However, it has not yet been included in an official gem release yet.

If you want to work around this issue for now, you have two options:

-Point to the neo4-core master branch

-Auto-start Neo4j on startup using the following monkey patch. This skirts around the thread-safety issue, because Rails won't accept any requests until Neo4j finishes starting up.

```rb
#config/initializers/neo4j.rb
require 'neo4j'
module Neo4j
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    initializer "neo4j.db.start", :after => "neo4j.start" do |app|
      Neo4j.start if app.config.neo4j.auto_start
    end
  end
end

#config/application.rb
config.neo4j.auto_start = true
```

Note that even with these fixes in place, I've still had trouble with the puma web server throwing strange exceptions. I would recommend [torquebox-lite](https://github.com/torquebox/torquebox-lite) for production use - it's never fallen over for me.

**UPDATE**: Neo4j.rb v2.2.4 (released on May 19, 2013) includes this fix, so this patch will no longer be necessary after you upgrade.